# hiddenQuestions.find is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this:

```
  var hiddenQuestions = listQuestions.hidden_questions;
  var find = hiddenQuestions.find(function (questionId) {
    return parseInt(question.id) === parseInt(questionId);
  });
  question.open = !find;
  return question;
})
```

But it is giving me the below error on the console: `Uncaught TypeError: hiddenQuestions.find is not a function`

Can anyone please point me what's wrong there?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: put the value in the console, you can check if it is coming null or undefined. console.log("questions-",listQuestions.hidden_questions);

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your `listQuestions.hidden_questions` is not an array so you cannot use `find`. Better ensure that the said object is neither **null** nor **undefined** before calling the `find` function. Otherwise, please provide some more code context to narrow down the possibilities of where the problem may come from.